# Is resolution independent UI possible directly using QtDesigner?

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qt5.9

**I want to create a UI which remains the same in all possible resolutions**. I started with the **Qt Designer** wherein I set the geometry of my design window and when I change the resolution , the UI is not the same.

Things I tried:

1.I got the screen resolution using QT API and created a window programmatically to that resolution.But if this is the right approach,then I have to add other components programmatically. But my UI is quite big and it is time consuming creating all the UI components programmatically.

I looked at the following links:

- [Hand Coded GUI Versus Qt Designer GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387092/hand-coded-gui-versus-qt-designer-gui?rq=1)
- [Qt Creator - How to write the UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985051/qt-creator-how-to-write-the-ui?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Is it possible to rescale a Qt GUI without rewriting the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189238/is-it-possible-to-rescale-a-qt-gui-without-rewriting-the-code)

but still I am a bit unclear of how to proceed.

**Is there any way to achieve resolution independent UI using Qt Designer itself?If so, what is the approach?Else what is the work around?**

Comment: You should probably read through all of this Qt article: [High DPI Displays](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/highdpi.html).